# Prove that there is no other sub-limits?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

let $a_n$ be a sequence,

If I split it into two sub-sequences; one that holds the value for members with odd indexes and one for members with even indexes.
Then, why can't be a limit other than the limit of the two sub-sequences mentioned above (if they exist)?

---

I have an idea but can't write it formally, let a and b be the limits of the two sub-sequences and let's suppose there is a third one let's call it c. Then, There is N such that for each n>N all members of $a_n$ exist in very close area to a or b but not c.

Comment: What do you mean by "a limit other than the limit of the two sub-sequences"? Assuming we're talking about sequences of real numbers (or more generally, in a metric space), a sequence has at most one limit. Each sub-sequence is a sequence, so each has at most one limit.

Comment: I mean suppose $a_n=n$ then its members are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.... Then if we split it into two sequences: 1,3,5,7.... and 2,4,6,8.... Then why can't be a sub-limit that is different from the limit of the two splatted sequences (That cover all members of $a_n$?) (For example why 3 can't be a possible limit )

Comment: None of those sequences has a limit. If $a_n$ has a limit, then the even and odd subsequences (in fact, all subsequences) have the same limit. If $a_n$ has no limit, then the even and odd subsequences may or may not have limits, and if both do, they will be different. In that case, an arbitrary subsequence $a_{n_k}$ may converge to either of those two limits or may fail to converge, depending on whether or not $n_k$ contains infinitely many even and odd values. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point : limit points are also called accumulation points.  Given an infinite sequence $a_n$, if there is an (infinite) subsequence that converges to a limit L, then L denotes a Limit point of the sequence. An example would be the sequence 1, 1, 2, (1/2), 3, (1/3), 4, (1/4), ... The subsequence of even terms converges to 0, so 0 is a limit point of the sequence.  However, the sequence (as a whole) does not converge to any one point.  ...see next comment

Comment: It is well settled that if an infinite sequence (as a whole) converges to one point, then that sequence **always** has exactly 1 limit point, namely the point that the entire sequence converges to.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = x$ iff we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n = x$.

Theorem: Suppose that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$. Now suppose that $b_n$ is a subsequence of $a_n$; that is, suppose that $b_n = a_{k_n}$ where $k_n$ is strictly increasing. Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = a$.

Proof: take $\epsilon > 0$. Take some $M$ s.t. for all $n \geq M$, $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$. Then we note that for all $n$, we have $k_n \geq n$ (because $k_0 \geq 0$ and $k$ is strictly increasing). Then for all $n \geq N$, we have $k_n \geq n \geq N$ and thus $|b_n - a| = |a_{k_n} - a| < \epsilon$.

Thus, by the $N-\epsilon$ definition of limits, we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = a$.

In your case, we have two subsequences $c_n = a_{2n}$ and $d_n = a_{2n + 1}$ of $a$. Then if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$, we would have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d_n = a$ by the above.

On the other hand, suppose we have $a_n$, $c_n$, and $d_n$ as defined above and that $c_n$ and $d_n$ have the same limit $x$. It can be shown that $a_n$ also has limit $x$ as follows:

Suppose we have $\epsilon > 0$. Take $N, M$ s.t. for all $n \geq N$, $|c_n - x| < \epsilon$ and for all $m \geq M$, $|d_n - x| < \epsilon$. Define $K = \max(2N, 2M + 1)$. Now suppose we have $k \geq K$. Case 1: $k$ is even. Write $k = 2n$. Then $n \geq N$. Then $|a_k - x| = |a_{2n} - x| = |c_n - x| < \epsilon$. Case 2: $k$ is odd. Write $k = 2m + 1$. Then $m \geq M$. Then $|a_k - x| = |a_{2m + 1} - x| = |d_n - x| < \epsilon$. Then by the definition of limit, we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = x$.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, who said that $a_n$ converges at all?

Comment: @ArielCohen I have edited the answer to more fully answer the question.